# Use two bootstrap country pickers on one page - do not get populated

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form on my page on which I want to use two country pickers. Just like this:

```
<label for="CLInput">Country</label>
<select class="form-control bfh-countries" id="CLInput" data-country="NL"></select>
```

When I use this once, it works fine. However when I add another country picker (using a different id) none of them gets populated.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to `id`, please add `name` attribute in the select tag to make the plugin work with multiple cases.